# How to send a javascript variable to a PHP file in Magento project?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I have this file that contains a javascript variable:

src/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/smv/order/sales/creditmemo/refund.phtml

```
<p>
    <select name="creditmemo[reason]">
        <option value="wrong">Fraudulent</option>
        <option value="not_available">Unavailable</option>
        <option value="request">Request</option>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            var cancelAndRefundSelectElement = document.getElementsByName("creditmemo[reason]")[0];

    </script>

</p>
```

Now, I need to send that variable to this PHP file:

src/app/code/code/Mage/Sales/model/Order/Creditmemo.php

```
public function reason(){


return 
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to call it from there and return it.

The code is longer, but I just wrote that the necessary things for the sake of the example.

Basically, how can I send the value of the variable from the 1st file (phtml) to the 2nd file (php)?

Thank you!

Comment: You can not send Javascript variable to PHP variable because Javascript is client-side and PHP is server side. You can use a cookie for handling values of your variable because the cookie is supported client side as well as server side both.

Comment: why not use wrap your select option in a form and pass its value to the other php file  using post method ?

Comment: I'm new to PHP, can you give me an example on how to do it? Thanks!